# Can I turn eNom in to a slave, or somehow work side by side?

Tags: domain-name-system, master-slave

I ran out of space at eNom, and can add no more sub domains.
Now I'am setting up bind9 on my server and was wondering, can I turn eNom in to a slave.
I would have preferred running my dns server as the slave but there is no option of setting NS records at eNom.

I did register my Name Servers with eNom as in ns1.mydomain.com but that appears to only work at eNom internally. I can set those Name Server for other domains within enom, but they don't show up anywhere else. Seams they work like an alias for the eNom Name Server.

So I am wondering if I can turn enom in to a slave.
Meaning would somethig like this work:

```
mydomain.com.        IN    NS    dns1.name-services.com.
mydomain.com.        IN    NS    dns2.name-services.com.
```

Where **dns1.name-services.com** is eNom's

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you're trying to accomplish - you can certainly add them as an additional delegate on your zone and in your registrar's information, but I don't think that you can expect them to actually host a slaved copy of your zone that's transferred from your BIND server.  Can you maybe give an overview of what you want your ideal name resolution architecture for your domain to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to set your BIND server as the *source* of your zones but you want to use other 3rd party servers as the *authoritative* servers for the domains, acting as slaves to your BIND host?

This can definitely be done and I have a similar setup. This is my setup (kind of like a CDN for DNS).

```
[zone host]-- axfr --+-- [ns1/3rd party slave]--+
                     +-- [ns2/3rd party slave]--+-- dns -- [rest of the net]
```

I have my host server hosting all my zones and providing AXFR zone transfers to a bunch of slave DNS services (there are many available on the internet). You will be able to find guides on how to do this with bind.

I have my domains then pointed to these slave servers as the authoritative servers (both primary and secondary) for these domains. All this requires is a configuration change at your registrar, eNom.

I also have a vanity NS setup so that *ns1.mydomain.com* actually points to the authoritative server IPs and not my host. eNom should be able to setup a vanity NS setup for you.

You will need to have A records set to resolve to these 3rd party server IPs as your ns1/ns2 and also register the vanity NS.

Comment: Thanks, this is better then I was hopping. I found a few and will try this one https://dns.he.net/

Comment: it'll work. i'm using it too.