# Using own NS for your domain

Tags: domain-name-system, ns-record

I have a dedicated server from 1and1.

Let's say I have a domain named `example.com`. Can I point it at `ns1.example.com` and `ns2.example.com` and use it for other domains?

Comment: Note that if you don't register glue records with your registrar, this will form an unresolvable loop. "How do I find the name server for `example.com`?" "Ask `ns1.example.com` or `ns2.example.com`." "Okay, how do I find the IP address for those so I can ask them?" "Ask the nameserver for `example.com`." "That's what I wanted to know in the first place!"

Comment: @DavidSchwartz; I did this before you write it. I went my registar. Create 2 ns with my domain and point it to the IP of my dedicated. If you write it as an answer I could choose as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I logged in my registar and created 2 ns with my domain and point it to the IP of my dedicated. Now it works.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, but unless you've got another, geographically diverse, server to host the second nameserver, you shouldn't.  There are whole RFCs (ie RFC2182) on how DNS should be run; I'd suggest reading them *before* you embark on this adventure.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you host your DNS, you may be opening yourself to DNS cache poisoning, or leaking information you don't want to share (think Active Directory).

I would advise against hosting your own DNS; since you are increasing your surface area of a DOS.  Your ISP is probably (hopefully) better than you are at this.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the situation, you may want to consider a setup similar to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/346767/can-i-turn-enom-in-to-a-slave-or-somehow-work-side-by-side/346812#346812) other question.